# Type mismatch. Required: session.Expression[Boolean], found: Validation[CheckBuilder[JsonPathCheckType, JsonNode, String]

Tags: scala, gatling

I am getting this error which I am not sure what it means:

**Type mismatch. Required: session.Expression[Boolean], found: Validation[CheckBuilder[JsonPathCheckType, JsonNode, String] with SaveAs[JsonPathCheckType, JsonNode, String]]**

I am trying to retrieve a value called "title" from an API response body for a user's created assessment and save it as "titleSession". Because not every user that is fed into the simulation will have associated created assessments I am trying to make the saving of "titleSession" only occur if there already exists a "title", hence the doIf:

```
  private val manifestInfoQuickAssign = getManifestInfoForCreatingAssessement
    .check(status.is(Ok),
      doIf(jsonPath("$.results[*].matches.assessment[*].title").find.exists()){
          jsonPath("$.results[*].matches.assessment[*].title").saveAs(titleSession)
      }
    )
```

For context, here are the current Gatling imports I have imported:

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef.exec
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
```

Also here is "getManifestInfoForCreatingAssessment":

```
  val getManifestInfoForCreatingAssessement = http("Get custom assessment metadata (Manifest-Resources) resources")
    .get("/api/onesearch/v1/metadata")
    .headers(getHeaderMap)
    .queryParam("collection", "Assessments")
    .queryParam("options", "search-assessments-json") //search-assessments-json for ui possibly
    .queryParam("start", "1")
    .queryParam("pageLength", "1000")
    .queryParam("searchView", "results")
    .queryParam("q", "userId:${userId} sort:title")
    .check(status is Ok,
      jsonPath("$.total").saveAs("totalAssessments"))
```

If anyone knows how to save the "title" if it exists, even without the doIf or resolve the error, that would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong, you can't use `doIf` there.

You're looking for the `optional` validation criterion: https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/check/#validating